# Unexpected end-of-input in nested if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I'm using the acts-as-commentable gem and I want to send out a notification email when a comment is left - depending on the type of the record.

```
def send_comment_notification_email
    klass = Object.const_get commentable_type
    resource = klass.find_by(id: commentable_id)

    if parent_id.nil?

      if commentable_type == "Review" 
        # CommentMailer.new_review_comment(resource, self).deliver
      elsif commentable_type == "Movie"
        if !resource.company_id.nil?
          CommentMailer.new_company_stack_comment(resource, self).deliver
        end
        if resource.owner_type == 'User'
          CommentMailer.new_personal_stack_comment(resource, self).deliver
        end
      elsif commentable_type == "MovieItem"
        unless resource.stack.owner.nil?    
          # CommentMailer.new_stack_item_comment(resource, self).deliver
        end
      end

    end   

  end
```

Why am I getting an error:

> SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end:

Can I not nest if statements like this?

Comment: This portion of the code has no syntax problems. The syntax error must be in another part of the file.

Comment: Would you mind to make more precise what `end` is the cause of problems?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace to know which line causes problems ? Your code looks okay so stack trace will help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to missing `end` for the nested if at line number 10. I would suggest you to use inline conditional there. You code will be something like this:

```
def send_comment_notification_email
    klass = Object.const_get commentable_type
    resource = klass.find_by(id: commentable_id)

    if parent_id.nil?

      if commentable_type == "Review" 
        # CommentMailer.new_review_comment(resource, self).deliver
      elsif commentable_type == "Movie"
          CommentMailer.new_company_stack_comment(resource, self).deliver unless resource.company_id.nil?
        end
        if resource.owner_type == 'User'
          CommentMailer.new_personal_stack_comment(resource, self).deliver
        end
      elsif commentable_type == "MovieItem"
        unless resource.stack.owner.nil?    
          # CommentMailer.new_stack_item_comment(resource, self).deliver
        end
      end

    end   

  end
```

You can read about inline conditionals [here](http://seejohncode.com/2012/07/31/ruby-gotcha-single-line-conditionals/)